# Arguments and input in classes issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am programming in Python. The problem is that when I use a variable to input a string to the class, I get this error. Can you tell me what is the problem with it? I have already tried single quotation within the input.

[image]

This is the code

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100

    def eat(self,food):
        if food == 'ham':
            self.health -= 50
        elif food == 'apple':
            self.health += 60
        else:
            print "rowing answer"

huseein = Hero("Husma")
print huseein.name
print huseein.health
x = str(input("enter ham or apple"))
huseein.eat(str(x))
print huseein.health
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you've tried and what error you are getting?

Comment: I have uploaded the image but it doesn't appear I will try to upload it again

Comment: You shouldn't be uploading images of code anyway. Post your code as text in the question.

Comment: I uploaded the image now it appears in the question

Comment: I also print the code in the question thanks

Comment: Dear admin I have edit the post so it fit your requirement can you please publish it

Comment: there is no need to ask for the question to be re-opened - this is automagically done

Comment: OK when!!!! Do you think

Answer (score 1):

### Use `raw_input`

On Python 2, `input()` is equal to `eval(raw_input())` – it evaluates your input as it was a python code.